# How do I scan and print an Unsigned Char in C?

Tags: c, unsigned

I am trying to ask the user for an input, have that input be set as an unsigned char, and then print it out. For example, the input will ask me "Input x:" and I put in 0xABCD as the input. I need it to print out "0xABCD" as well.

Here's what I have so far:

```
unsigned char x;
printf("Input x:");
scanf("%s, &x);

printf("%u", x);
```

It gives me 0 instead of 0xABCD.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A char is just one character, you need an array of chars.

Comment: Sure a 16 bit value fits into an `unsigned char`?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Dial the warning level to the maximum and read all the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `"%hhu"` as the format specifier to read an `unsigned char`. See the table at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf.

```
unsigned char x;
printf("Input x:");
scanf("%hhu", &x);
```

Note that if you use this format specifier, the input has to be a number. It cannot be a character. `65` will be a valid input but `A` won't.

Coming to your problem of wanting to use `0xABCD` as input, that value is too large to fit into an `unsigned char`. You can use:

```
unsigned x;
printf("Input x:");
scanf("%x", &x);
```

To print that number as `0xABCD`, you can use:

```
printf("0x%X\n", x);
```

If you don't mind the number being printed as `0xabcd`, you can use:

```
printf("%#x\n", x);
```

Comment: `%d` or `%u` can be used ?

Comment: You're right, but I don't think this is what OP intends to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
 scanf("%s, &x);
```

invokes undefined behavior. `x`is of type `char` and you cannot use `%s` to scan the value.

What you need is to define a `char` array at least to be able to hold your expected input.

If you like to have a second approach, you can do something like

- scan the input as (unsigned) integer using `%x`
- print the same using `%#X` format specifier.

**[See it <kbd>live</kbd>](http://rextester.com/CITJMT38917)**

Answer (score 0):

A string is an array of characters terminated by `'\0'`. You're reading a string into a single character, which is undefined behavior.

Your code should really look something like this:

```
unsigned char x[64];
printf("Input x:");
scanf("%63s, x); /* use the size of buffer to prevent buffer overflows */

printf("%s", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

In any ways "0xABCD" can't be treated as a 'char'. A char can store a 8 bit value, so from 0 to 255 (if unsigned), and the given number 0xABCD is equal to 43981.

You can read it as a string or read it as a hexadecimal value (which must be an unsigned). For this case an example:

```
unsigned int x;
printf("Number: ");
scanf("%x", &x);
printf("%d / %X\n", x, x);
```

will give:

```
Number: 0xABCD
43981 / ABCD
```

If treated as a string you will have to treat it an other way (sscanf…).

Answer (score 0):

there is no char equivalent, use int instead.

```
int main(){

    unsigned  int x;
    printf("Input x:");
    scanf("%x", &x);

    printf("\n%d (%#x)\n", x); 
}
```